# DRF: How to group the output of serialized data by a specific field of the model?

Tags: django-rest-framework

models.py

```
class Mailing(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    tag_filter = models.ForeignKey(
        Tag,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="tag_filter"
    )
    code_mobile_operator_filter = models.ForeignKey(
        Code,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="code_filter"
    )
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()



class Mail(models.Model):
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False,)
    mailing = models.ForeignKey(
        Mailing,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="mail",
        related_query_name="mail_mailing"
    )
    client = models.ForeignKey(
        Client,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="mail",
        related_query_name="mail_client"
    )
```

views.py

```
@action(
        detail=False,
        methods=['get'],
        pagination_class=LimitPagePagination,
        # permission_classes=(permissions.IsAdminUser, )
    )
    def get_stat_all_mailings(self, request):
        mail = Mailing.objects.annotate(
            total_mail=Count('mail_mailing'),
            total_sent_mail=Count('mail_mailing__status',
                                  filter=Q(mail_mailing__status=True)),
            client=F('mail_mailing__client'))
        pages = self.paginate_queryset(mail)
        serializer = GetStatMailings(
            pages,
            many=True,
            context={'request': request}
        )
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class GetStatMailings(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    start_time = serializers.DateTimeField()
    end_time = serializers.DateTimeField()
    tag_filter = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Tag.objects.all())
    code_mobile_operator_filter = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Code.objects.all()
    )
    text = serializers.CharField()
    total_mail = serializers.IntegerField()
    total_sent_mail = serializers.IntegerField()
    client = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Client.objects.all())
```

How to group the output of serialized data by id field? Now I have this conclusion.

```
"id": 1,
"start_time": "2023-09-24T22:00:00+03:00",
"end_time": "2023-09-24T23:00:00+03:00",
"tag_filter": 1,
"code_mobile_operator_filter": null,
"text": "...",
"total_mail": 1,
"total_sent_mail": 0,
"client": 1
```

We need such a conclusion.

```
"id": 1,
"start_time": "2023-09-24T22:00:00+03:00",
"end_time": "2023-09-24T23:00:00+03:00",
"tag_filter": 1,
"code_mobile_operator_filter": null,
"text": ".....",
"total_mail": 1,
"total_sent_mail": 0,
"client": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ]
```

For the annotation of the field, the client tried to use ArrayAgg, it did not help. Also, I was able to achieve the desired result using SerializerMethodField, but then the number of requests increases.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use SerializerMethodField for client.
`client = serializers.SerializerMethodField(help_text="clients")`

````
    @swagger_serializer_method(serializer_or_field=serializers.CharField)
    def get_client(obj):
        \\your logics
        return clients```

or you can add a new serialzer for clients and add it to GetStatMailings serializer (nested serializers).
````